# Определение диска, на котором находится файл

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Имеется bash-скрипт, как из него определить на каком диске он находится? (/dev/sd*)

Comment: Точки монтирования можно посмотреть командой `mount`

Comment: Какой скрипт ? Из скрипта определить где скрипт ? Тогда покажите этот скрипт.

Comment: Видимо, нужно использовать связку `pwd` (даст текущий каталог) и потом соотносить с точками монтирования.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вопрос не имеет «правильного» ответа, т.к. файл вполне может располагаться и не на (физическом) блочном устройстве (или не на одном — при использовании надстроек типа raid/lvm/и т.п.). в оперативной памяти, например (сюда относятся все виды сетевого доступа и прочей «виртуализации» файловых систем).

а вообще местоположение файла/каталога можно узнать, например, с помощью программы *df*. примеры:

```
$ df /proc/net/arp 
Filesystem     1K-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on
proc                   0     0         0    - /proc

$ df /media/smb/some.file
Filesystem          1K-blocks       Used  Available Use% Mounted on
//localshare/files 7811746812 2065676236 5746070576  27% /media/smb

$ df ~/bin/
Filesystem                1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/host--vg-root 462960456 326096732 113276908  75% /
```

если используется версия программы от проекта *gnu*, то для простоты обработки результата можно указать нужные столбцы вывода:

```
$ df --output=source ~/bin/
Filesystem
/dev/mapper/host--vg-root
```

---

ах, да. про путь к скрипту. внутри скриптов, интерпретируемых posix-совместимой оболочкой, можно обратиться к [переменной `$0`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_02):

> 0
>       (Zero.) Expands to the name of the shell or shell script.

т.е., можно воспользоваться такой, например, конструкцией:

```
fs=$(df --output=source "$0" | tail -n 1)
echo "скрипт $0 располагается на $fs"
```

Comment: `realpath $0`, наверное. И `readlink` конечно. Кстати, а с unionfs и `mount -o bind` тестировали?