# Получить свободное место на текущем устройстве

Tags: bash

Есть команда df -H, которая показывает файловую систему устройства, размер, сколько осталось и куда смонтировано. Как мне вытащить только свободное место и только того устройство, на котором запускается скрипт?
Например я запускаю скрипт из папки ~/1/2/3/4.sh. У меня этот файл лежил на /dev/sda1 который монтируется в /home.

Comment: с помощью программы bash это сделать теоретически возможно, но очень трудоёмко. проще воспользоваться упомянутой вами в вопросе программой *df*: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/744908/178576 (упомянув нужный вам столбец в опции `--output`)

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно получить только `available`, то так

```
df --output=avail . | tail -1
```